# What will be printed by this line and why?

Tags: c

What will be printed by this line?

```
printf("hello\n") | (printf("goodbye\n") || printf("world\n"));
```

After tested, it printed:

```
hello
goodbye
```

But I still don't know why and still stuck on it, any hints will be really appreciated! By the way I know that printf() returns the number of characters output but still do not get the logic behind that.

Comment: Hint: perhaps figure out what `|` and `||` do?

Comment: Your question title appears to conflict with your question. You *know* what it does...

Comment: I know | is the bit-wise OR, and || is the OR operator, but still don't know why it printed goodbye but not world :(

Comment: Check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: Maybe you figure out the way in C lines get invoked?;)

Comment: Ah ha, thank you very much, I think I might get how it works now :)

Answer (score 3):

```
|  - Bitwise OR operator
|| - Logical OR operator

printf("hello\n") | (printf("goodbye\n") || printf("world\n"));
```

In this case, both `printf("hello\n")` and `printf("goodbye\n")` will be executed since you have used `|` between them. Since it is bitwise operation, both will be executed. Also `printf` returns the number of characters printed. Hence in your case, `printf("hello\n") | printf("goodbye\n")` will result in `6 | 8` = 0110 | 1000 = 1110 = 14 (in decimal).

Hence the expression becomes equivalent to `14 || printf("world\n")`. Since 14 (being non-zero) itself satisfies the Logical OR check, it will not proceed to `printf("world\n")` which would be 6.

Comment: Thanks @Kay for the edit. I need to do some research how to do it this way :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
(printf("goodbye\n") || printf("world\n"))
```

Both "goodbye" and "world" are TRUE statements. Hence, it is taking "goodbye" as the first one to execute in order.

Try this for more clarification

```
printf(printf("hello\n") | (printf(NULL) || printf("world\n")));
Output:
hello
world
```

Because "NULL" is FALSE and "world" is TRUE. (0 || 1  = 1)

Thanks,